# Grails : How I do mock other methods of a class under test which might be called internally during testing

Tags: testing, grails, groovy, mocking, tdd

I am writing a test for methodA() in a service class similar to the one given below.

```
Class SampleService {
  def methodA(){
     methodB()
  }

  def methodB(){
  }
}
```

When I test methodA(), I need to be able to mock the call to methodB() when testing methodA(). I am using version 2.0.x of grails. In the 1.3.x distributions, I would write a self mock like this

```
def sampleServiceMock = mockFor(SampleService) 
sampleServiceMock.demand.methodB { -> }
```

But this doesn't work in the 2.0.x versions. I was wondering what are the other ways of mocking methodB() when testing methodA()

Comment: Does anybody know how to do this for Grails 3.2.8 with Spock?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For this kind of problem I actually avoid mocks and use the built-in groovyProxy ability to cast a map of closures as a proxy object.  This gives you an instance with some methods overridden, but others passed through to the real class:

```
class SampleService {
    def methodA() {
        methodB()
    }

    def methodB() {
        return "real method"
    }
}

def mock = [methodB: {-> return "mock!" }] as SampleService

assert "mock!" == mock.methodA()
assert "real method" == new SampleService().methodA()
```

I like that only changes an instance, can be done in a single line, and doesn't mess with the metaclass of anything outside of that instance that needs to be cleaned up.

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a great way of mocking behaviors. I still miss the ability to self mock using grails' mockFor() :(

Comment: Brilliant. This helped me as well as the test I had was creating Spock closures and was unable to assert the actual values returned from the controller (when mocking a service call).

Comment: What if the methods take in parameters. I am trying that an I keep getting; `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: ... is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

Answer (score 13):

There are a lot of mocking alternatives with Groovy. You can see some documentation of [Groovy Mocks](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Mocks), [using Maps and Expandos instead of Mocks](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Developer+Testing+using+Maps+and+Expandos+instead+of+Mocks) or [using Closures instead of Mocks](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Developer+Testing+using+Closures+instead+of+Mocks).

In your example, I'll use metaprogramming capabilities of Groovy.

```
void testMethodA() {
    service = new SampleService()
    service.metaClass.methodB = { -> return "what you want" }
    service.methodA()
    assert "your condition"
}
```

Comment: I did finally use this approach to mocking. But, semantically speaking, changing a class's signature to make a test pass seems extreme :)

Comment: The links( Groovy Mocks, using Maps and Expandos instead of Mocks or using Closures instead of Mocks) are not working anymore, please fix or delete them. Thanks.